# Photomos relay AQW212EH off state capacitance issue passing AC

Tags: solid-state-relay

I'm working on making a telephone exchange based on this [design](http://www.aholme.co.uk/Exchange/Schematics.htm)

This is the second time I've made this exchange, my new version has 8 lines instead of 4, DTMF integration and connection to an outside line (well another PABX).

When I dial a number, say extn 1 to 2, I get an audible 50hz buzzing when "ringing" (with the AC feed) to the destination phone in the source phones receiver. This is odd as the relays on the destination array phone should route the ringing AC only to the destination phone. The relays I'm using, [aqw212eh](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1237077/Panasonic/AQW212EH/1), come in pairs on the IC and what seems to be happening is that the AC is leaking through the adjacent relay in the IC and appearing in the source phones receiver as a buzz.

The relays I am using have two different manufactures markers marks on them; Some are marked with a M in a circle and the other is marked NAIS. With a little experimenting I found the one's marked M don't seem to exhibit the issue but the ones marked NAIS do. I can swap one for the other which fixes the buzzing. Unfortunately I don't have enough of the "M's" to completely replace the NAIS ones.

I found an app. note [here](https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/PanasonicPhotomosRelayPhotoMOSOutputCharacteristics.PDF) that says higher frequencies can pass through the Photomos as it has a degree of capacitance when "off". The note doesn't refer directly to the relays I'm using but I guess it's the same thing, and that is what's causing issue.

Are the NAIS made to a lower spec than the ones marked "M" which is allowing a lower frequency of AC to pass through them?

I've searched high a low but can't find any reference to this, though technically they should both be made to the same spec. I didn't have any of these kinds of issues on the previous exchange.

Comment: AQW212EH "Low-level off-state leakage current of max. 1 μA" -- a real (physical) relay would probably have a leakage current of 1pA; a million times less.  For switching a light bulb, either will work, but when 50/60Hz hum is present, these will conduct that hum a million times more than a physical relay would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By way of an update I contacted Panasonic UK support who said the AC voltage is probably too high for the 212 which is causing clipping/buzzing (I'm using about 50 V so should be within tolerances, but the peak to peak is probably higher). They said I should try the 210 which has a higher voltage rating and this did indeed remove the buzzing.

Answer (score 0):

NAIS is a trademark for independent suppliers and not a manufacturer unless it says NAIS/Panasonic for example.  It is commonly used by Independent Distributors who generally buy hard to find parts when supplies are short.  They tend not employ engineers and no nothing about relay MTBF factors or coil saturation, frequency response or shading pole filtering from AC currents.

If some site says they have genuine NAIS parts, then you know they are just any Chinese supplier who makes it with the NAIS no-name brand. It ought to have equivalent voltage & Resistive current ratings but not all Relays are identical in every way such as reliability, something OMRON was well known for.  (the best in the past)

"F" I recall was used for Cadmium-free, and M will be some OEM factory-specific feature and is meaningless for a no-name brand without a datasheet.

This is just from my experience and glad you found a solution.